# Symfony2: Grouping Entities inside one file

Tags: php, class, symfony

I have created several custom exceptions and I want to groups them inside `Exceptions.php` but when I include the namespace in my Controller, I get a fatal error saying that the Class was "not found". It only works when I have it all separated in different files and the filename is the same as the class name.

Is there any way to group Classes in files?

Exception

```
<?php

namespace Test\MyBundle\Entities;

class SomeException extends \Exception{...}

class AnotherException extends \Exception{...}
```

Entity using the exception

```
<?php

namespace Test\MyBundle\Entities\MoneyManagement;

use Test\MyBundle\Entities\SomeException;

class MoneyManager{

    public function deposit(){

       throw new SomeException();
```

Comment: Any reason you can't have one file per class? its so much easier to read that way.

Comment: There is classmap option in composer.  I have not messed with it myself.  Like @Flosculus says, just keep them in their own file.

Comment: Symfony follows PSR-1 (and PSR-0 and PSR-2) and this standard defines that there must only be one class per file. https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md

Comment: @cliveza would you mind adding your comment as an answer so Dbugger can accept it? While there might be a workaround using composer's classmap configuration it would involve more code than benefit and we shouldn't encourage people to use bad practices/code against conventions. therefore PSR-1 only allowing 1 class per file is the correct answer here :)